# CTE ordering guarantees

Tags: postgresql, order-by, cte

I'm starting to make heavy use of CTEs for my postgres based application, and am wondering if selecting from a previous CTE statement guarantees any ordering?

E.g. is the order of rows for this query guaranteed?

```
WITH latest_logs AS (
    SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100
)
SELECT * FROM latest_logs;
```

What about this one?

```
WITH latest_logs AS (
    SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100
)
SELECT * FROM latest_logs WHERE my_field = 5;
```

Or do I always need to re-apply the `ORDER BY created DESC` every time I select from latest_logs?

Thanks :)